# Web service (on Amazon) security for iOS consumption

Tags: java, ios, web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I was wondering if anyone got experience with Java web services deployed on Tomcat and running in Amazon's EC2, in terms of security, when it comes to accessing the web services through iOS devices. REST and SOAP.

Is any best practise or guideline available, on how the web service can validate the caller, to ensure it is called from the app (and user) which is supposed to call it and not from any other program? Which classes/components, protocols, or techniques would you recommend?
Is AWS Identity and Access Management an option, and if, how would you use it?

Thanks for sharing and for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question to be you want only your iOS app to be the one to utilize the web service (Tomcat via REST/SOAP).  You don't want someone to write some custom program that pretends to be your app.

The best way is to ensure your iOS app verifies the SSL connection domain name and certificate to prevent someone from listening in and grabbing any "this is the actual app" identifiers.

Some common techniques I've used to help encourage that only the iOS app (and not some custom program) is the one communicating is to have it include the platform name and version along with a custom identifier string like "MyApp ABC123F3" embedded in the program code.  Another option is a mathematical routine that sends a rotating key number that only the server can verify.  Another option still would be a client-side SSL certificate embedded into the application, but that may be easier to find.

Of course if someone takes the binaries and reverse engineers them they can always get the secret string/algorithm and emulate it.  There isn't a whole lot you can do to stop that other than make it time consuming and difficult.